# Quotient Space and Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, quotient-spaces

Suppose that we have a vector space $X$ and two vector subspaces $A, B$ such that $A \subset B$. Is the following generally true?
$$
X / A \supset X/B
$$

Can we show this via equivalence classes? By this I mean given some $x \in X$ can we show $[x] \in X/B \implies [x] \in X/A$ where $[x]$ is the equivalence class generated by $x$.

Edit: The motivation for this question was trying to understand a step in the proof in Lax - Functional Analysis on pg. 13. For some operators $M$ and $G$ it claims because $R_M \supset R_{I+G}$ this implies $$codim(R_M) \leq codim (R_{I + G})$$

Here $R_M$ denotes the range of $M$.

Comment: You must stand on your head. What we can say is that $X/B$ is [naturally isomorphic to] a quotient of $X/A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. In the case that $A\subsetneq B$ we cannot say $X/A \supseteq X/B$, because they have different equivalence relations, hence different equivalence classes. This is a set-theoretic obstacle.

Unfortunately the assignment $i:X/B \hookrightarrow X/A$ sending the equivalence class $x+B$ to the equivalence class $x+A$ is **not** welldefined either. For an  element $b \in B\setminus A$ we would have to have
$$0+A = i(0+B) = i(b+B) =b +A \neq 0+A$$
where the last inequalities holds as $b\notin A$.

Comment: In the case of vector spaces, can we say $dim(X/A) > dim(X/B)$ ? Maybe using some identifications of equivalence classes using vector space structure? The motivation for the question was I was trying to see if I can show this without appealing to any basis (hence using only the equivalence relation $x \equiv_A y \iff x - y \in A$ for example).

Comment: Yes and no. The dimension of a space depends on the existence of a basis, so no matter what we do, bases will be a part of our proof somewhere. If you know about short exact sequences this would be a nice way to show that we have a strict inequality(if $A\neq B$). For a plain $\geq$ it suffices to note that the map $X/A \rightarrow X/B$ is surjective